# Is it possible to create a datatype that could represent multiple structs in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

Essentially I am creating a wrapper for SDL which is a media layer library for c++. I want my application to be able to create event watchers (like javascript's `addEventListener()`). I have several different event structs for different kinds of events as shown below. Is it possible to create a datatype called Event, that could be passed to a user defined handler function that would have the appropriate struct data.

```
struct MouseEvent {
    EventType type;
    int x;
    int y;
    uint8_t which;
    bool down;
};
struct KeyboardEvent {
    EventType type;
    int keyCode;
    const char* key;
    bool lshift;
    bool rshift;
    bool lctrl;
    bool rctrl;
    bool lalt;
    bool ralt;
    bool lmeta;
    bool rmeta;
    bool numlock;
    bool capslock;
    bool ctrl;
    bool shift;
    bool alt;
    bool meta;
};
struct WindowEvent {
    EventType type;
};
struct WheelEvent {
    EventType type;
    int x;
    int y;
    bool dir;
};
```

So for further explanation here is an example: the use clicks, so that creates a MouseEvent and passes that MouseEvent as an Event type to a function that checks for mousedown listeners. Is this a good way of doing this or am I just stupid.

I have looked into unions however when you use a union if a user wanted to access data within the event they would have to do something like `event.mouse.x` when I would much prefer it be accessed by just `event.x` Maybe I am just too picky

Comment: Have you looked into inheritance and polymorphism?

Comment: What exactly stopping you from defining this `Event` that contains all of these fields, which are filled in only if the field is appropriate for the specific event, if that's what you want to do? However, good modern C++ practice mandates type-safety, such as the one that's provided by `std::variant`. Using `std::variant` requires more work than just accessing a random field struct, but nobody has ever accused C++ of being easy.

Comment: It is preferable that each listener receive its appropriate event type (as it is done in C#). Otherwise, its hard to ensure that the appropriate `struct` is used as the system grow. If your mouse listener receive a `MouseEvent`, it also far easier to use and in general, this is preferred as it make easier to use the component.